# Is it possible to close an audit automatically?

Tags: phabricator

Consider the following scenario:

- Dev1 commits some buggy code on commit #1058;
- Dev2 notices the bug while browsing commits on Diffusion and thus *raises a concern* over commit #1058;
- Dev1 acknowledges his mistake and commits the corrected code on commit #1061.

At this point, is there a way to close the audit on commit #1058 automatically, say, through the commit message? Or is either Dev1 or Dev2 supposed to do it manually on Diffusion?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  I can't find anything in their source code or their documentation that would connect a commit message to another commit's Audit.

Comment: Actually it does detect mentions and reverting commits, and notes them between the summary and the diff contents. But audits are not automatically closed - that is up to the reviewer who raised the concern, as only they can really judge whether their concern was addressed or not.